# Toggle drop down won't work with multiple view using CI and Bootstrap

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I tried to load my header and my content inside controller. After fixing my script order, my drop down toggle in header won't work. I've tried to load header only and it worked, but my drop down toggle won't work if i load both header and content together. I load my header and my content using `$this->load->view()`. I've also included my header, my content, and also the controller.

**header_only**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark mb-5 align-center justify-content" height="30"  >
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="assets/img/foto.png">
        <img src="../assets/img/foto.png" height="30"alt="" >
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Beranda <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Monitoring dan Evaluasi
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo site_url('CapaianIKU') ?>">Capaian IKU Departemen/Prodi</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= site_url('triwulan')?>">Capaian IKU PTN BH Departemen/Prodi</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**content_only**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
      <h2 class="text-justify text-center">Hi<h2>
      <br>
      <h5 class="text-center">Have a good day<h5> 
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        /**Some validation here**/       
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $levelUser = $this->session->userdata('level');
        $data['nama'] = $this->session->userdata('nama');
        if($levelUser == "3"){
            $this->load->view('header_only',$data);
            $this->load->view('content_only');
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('another_header', $data);
            $this->load->view('content_only');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not telling us how you're loading the header and the content (I'll assume you're using two `$this->load->view()` calls, one for each view file. The first thing I'd reccommend you try is that you build your header until the `</head>` tag only and then your content view takes it from there until the closing `</html>` tag. Otherwise you're pretty much loading everything twice, and that's how you start getting javascript and CSS conflicts all around

Comment: Yes, i do load them using that function. I want to make my header and my content separately. Is there any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading js links again and again You should split the header as css and html like below code

In your  **header_only** file

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark mb-5 align-center justify-content" height="30"  >
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="assets/img/foto.png">
        <img src="../assets/img/foto.png" height="30"alt="" >
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Beranda <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Monitoring dan Evaluasi
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo site_url('CapaianIKU') ?>">Capaian IKU Departemen/Prodi</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= site_url('triwulan')?>">Capaian IKU PTN BH Departemen/Prodi</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

In your **content_only** file

```
<div class="container mt-5">
          <h2 class="text-justify text-center">Hi<h2>
          <br>
          <h5 class="text-center">Have a good day<h5> 
      </div>
```

Make **footer_only**  file and add it wherever you want

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now your controller will be below 
**Controller**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        /**Some validation here**/       
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $levelUser = $this->session->userdata('level');
        $data['nama'] = $this->session->userdata('nama');
        if($levelUser == "3"){
            $this->load->view('header_only',$data);
            $this->load->view('content_only');
            $this->load->view('footer_only');
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('another_header', $data);
            $this->load->view('content_only');
            $this->load->view('footer_only');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and i gain knowledge better in bootstrap